# Kncokout js Custom binding and jquery fade in fade out logic not working

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Hi I am following the fiddle posted here to build a SPA.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fjj7q/) the visibility of the div is toggled on selection change. I want to add animation fade in/fade out while the selection changes using custom binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fade= {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
    }  
}
```

updated [fiddle with fadetoggle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjj7q/201/).

I am not able to come up with the logic that will toggle only the selectedSection rather than all the div's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fade= {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()))
            $(element).fadeIn( "slow", "linear" );
        else
            $(element).fadeOut( "slow", "linear" ); //maybe you should hide here
            //$(element).hide();
    }  
}
```

Where `ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())` will be the result of `selectedSection() === 'profile'` (for example)

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/fjj7q/203/)